# Best way to exit application at CTRL+C interrupt on Linux. (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, linux

My application checks for user input in its main thread:

```
while (running)
{
    std::string console;
    if (std::getline(std::cin, console))
    {
        process(&console);
    }
}
```

Before that I have setup a sigaction to detect CTRL+C in conjunction with a function handler to shutdown other threads. 
Now, when a SIGINT occurs the application crashes; GDB output:
[image]

I was looking around and found other solutions such as non-blocking input reading: (pseudo-code)

```
while (running)
{
    if (input_avail())
    {
        getinput
        process
    }
    else
        sleep(1);
}
```

But even that fails for me at the sleep function (nanosleep):
[image]

So I'm quite curious on how other people achieve this?

(Using g++ v4.8.2 Kernel 3.10)

**Additional info requested:**

Before the main thread loop:

```
struct sigaction sigIntHandler;
sigIntHandler.sa_handler = signalinfo;
sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;

sigaction(SIGTERM, &sigIntHandler, NULL);
sigaction(SIGQUIT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);
sigaction(SIGINT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);
```

Signal handler:

```
void signalinfo(int signum)
{
    // Only setting a flag so threads know to exit.
    pCore->Termination(signum);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you handle the signal? Correctly handling UNIX signals in a multithreaded program is absolutely not trivial.

Comment: _"Before that I have setup a sigaction to detect CTRL+C i"_ I can't spot that in your code sample. Provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as usual please! I absoutely can't understand why this question is upvoted? Unclear language tags, incomplete code sample, insufficient debugging efforts, ...

Comment: `cin` does not provide interruptible io.  Write your own stream back end that does provide interruptible io using posix select and stdin file handles?

Comment: You're in gdb.   gdb will stop execution and print a stack trace on that signal per default.   Is your app also "crashing" when you run it outside of gdb?

Comment: This entire question makes no sense. The fact that GDB shows that `SIGINT` is raised does not mean there's anything wrong. That's the normal behaviour of Ctrl-C, and it's normal for `SIGINT` to kill the application. Why are you doing anything special at all? What about the default behaviour is wrong for your particular program?

Comment: Added the code snippets.. @hvd Well without GDB I get a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: @Mellnik Then continue from gdb after getting the signal, keep going until you get to the segmentation fault, and investigate *that*. Or, alternatively, set up your system to save a crash dump after a segmentation fault (`ulimit -c unlimited`), run without gdb, and load the dump in gdb afterwards. The `INT` signal is not the problem.

Comment: Nitpicking:  Your program is not checking for input, it is waiting (blocking) until the User enters a newline.  You may want to use something that is non-blocking so you can periodically check if the User has provided input.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it answers your question, but the documentation of the XBoard protocol explains some common strategies how engine engine handle reading from stdin.

It basically sketches how you might implement your non-blocking pseudo code.

Source: [XBoard protocol (6. Hints on input/output)](https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/engine-intf.html)

> ... on the input side, you are likely to want to poll during your search and stop it if new input has come in. If you implement pondering, you'll need this so that pondering stops when the user makes a move. You should also poll during normal thinking on your move, so that you can implement the "?" (move now) command, and so that you can respond promptly to a "result", "force", or "quit" command if xboard wants to end the game or terminate your engine. Buffered input makes polling more complicated -- when you poll, you must stop your search if there are either characters in the buffer or characters available from the underlying file descriptor.
>
> The most direct way to fix this problem is to use unbuffered operating system calls to read (and poll) the underlying file descriptor directly. On Unix, use read(0, ...) to read from standard input, and use select() to poll it. See the man pages read(2) and select(2). (Don't follow the example of GNU Chess 4 and use the FIONREAD ioctl to poll for input. It is not very portable; that is, it does not exist on all versions of Unix, and is broken on some that do have it.) On Win32, you can use either the Unix-like _read(0, ...) or the native Win32 ReadFile() to read. Unfortunately, under Win32, the function to use for polling is different depending on whether the input device is a pipe, a console, or something else. (More Microsoft brain damage here -- did they never hear of device independence?) For pipes, you can use PeekNamedPipe to poll (even when the pipe is unnamed). For consoles, you can use GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents. For sockets only, you can use select(). It might be possible to use WaitForSingleObject more generally, but I have not tried it. Some code to do these things can be found in Crafty's utility.c, but I don't guarantee that it's all correct or optimal.
>
> A second way to fix the problem might be to ask your I/O library not to buffer on input. It should then be safe to poll the underlying file descriptor as described above. With C, you can try calling setbuf(stdin, NULL). However, I have never tried this. Also, there could be problems if you use scanf(), at least with certain patterns, because scanf() sometimes needs to read one extra character and "push it back" into the buffer; hence, there is a one-character pushback buffer even if you asked for stdio to be unbuffered. With C++, you can try cin.rdbuf()->setbuf(NULL, 0), but again, I have never tried this.
>
> A third way to fix the problem is to check whether there are characters in the buffer whenever you poll. C I/O libraries generally do not provide any portable way to do this. Under C++, you can use cin.rdbuf()->in_avail(). This method has been reported to work with EXchess. Remember that if there are no characters in the buffer, you still have to poll the underlying file descriptor too, using the method described above.
>
> A fourth way to fix the problem is to use a separate thread to read from stdin. This way works well if you are familiar with thread programming. This thread can be blocked waiting for input to come in at all times, while the main thread of your engine does its thinking. When input arrives, you have the thread put the input into a buffer and set a flag in a global variable. Your search routine then periodically tests the global variable to see if there is input to process, and stops if there is. WinBoard and my Win32 ports of ICC timestamp and FICS timeseal use threads to handle multiple input sources.